# Which table is used when using class inheritance for models?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on a .NET Core 3.1 Web API. Suppose I have the following model classes:

This is a model that points to an underlying database table called TableA:

```
[Table("TableA")]
public class TableA
{
    public string ColumnA { get; set; }
}
```

This is a model that inherits from TableA but gets extra columns from a view in the database:

```
[Table("ViewTableA")]
public class ViewTableA : TableA
{
    public string ColumnA { get; set; }
    other properties from view ...
}
```

When reading from the database I will query using the ViewTableA model.  Since the ViewTableA has the attribute `[Table("ViewTableA")]` entity framework with generate the query to pull data from the ViewTableA view.

My question is if I had the following:

```
ViewTableA objA = new ViewTableA(){ populate properties here};
TableA objB = (TableA)objA;
```

If I were to add objB to the DBContext and save the changes which table/view would it hit?  The TableA table since objB is of type `TableA` which has an attribute of `[Table("TableA")]` or would it still hit the view called `ViewTableA`?

Comment: I think you just have to add objB to the correct DbSet.  And however it actually behaves, I believe behavior is undefined if you don't.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, that does not answer my question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment.  You can easily test the current behavior.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Can you please elaborate on your initial comment? I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: objB won't be change tracked until you call `db.Set<T>().Add(objB);`  If you call `db.Set<ViewTableA>().Add(objB)`, all is well.  If you call `db.Set<TableA>().Add(objB)` EF might insert into TableA or ViewTableA, or fail.  I'm not sure which, and you shouldn't rely on the behavior.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I believe that answers my question. Please post it as the answer so I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objB` won't be change tracked until you call `db.Set<T>().Add(objB);` If you call `db.Set<ViewTableA>().Add(objB)`, all is well. If you call `db.Set<TableA>().Add(objB)` EF might insert into TableA or ViewTableA, or fail. I'm not sure which, and you shouldn't rely on the behavior.